# Where are icons stored?

Tags: icons, themes

I want to change an icon of a specific theme. Where do themes save their icons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the Unity Launcher .desktop files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40931/where-are-the-unity-launcher-desktop-files)

Comment: @Lucio no, it's not. That Q is about `.desktop` files and location is not the same.

Comment: You're right, I totally confused it.

Comment: The link I was hunting for when I found this question was https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#install_icons ; I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Globally: `/usr/share/icons/`
or in your home folder : `~/.local/share/icons`

Comment: Here's some other locations apparently, too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/476233/how-to-include-environment-variable-in-launcher-for-icon/476710#476710.

Answer (score 28):

There are several places: (in bracets some examples)

- `/usr/share/pixmaps/` ( chromium-browser.png display-im6.q16.xpm firefox.png flash-player-properties.png gimp.xpm gvim.svg texstudio.xpm )
- `/usr/share/app-install/icons/` ( adobeflashplugin.png julia.svg texmaker.png thunderbird.png vim.svg vlc.png wine.svg grace.svg)
- `~/.local/share/icons/` ( soffice.png java-lang-thread.png org-jabref-jabrefmain.png) one of the places where Ubuntu searches for icons, if you use relative path
- `/usr/share/icons/...` and subfolders ( matlab.png .../hicolor/scalable/apps/chromium-browser.svg .../hicolor/scalable/apps/geany.svg .../hicolor/scalable/apps/okular.svgz .../default.kde4/48x48/apps/acroread.png)
- `/usr/share/...` just subfolders ( .../vlc/vlc.ico .../gimp/2.0/images/gimp-logo.png ) but this one is more for icons used in the program that the logo of the program
- `/snap/...` just subfolders ( .../inkscape/3080/meta/gui/inkscape.svg .../languagetool/10/snap/gui/icon.png )
- `~/.icons` related to freedesktop.org ([source1](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/speicherort-der-desktop-icons/), [source2](https://askubuntu.com/a/476710/676490) )

Most of the folders are already announced here, all sources I used:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/6010/676490
- https://askubuntu.com/a/43951/676490
- https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/speicherort-der-desktop-icons/
- [Why so many files in /usr/share/app-install/desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/464807/676490)

Answer (score 27):

`/usr/share/icons/` typically contains pre-installed themes (shared by all users)
`~/.icons/` typically contains folders with the themes installed by the user.

Also, many applications have their icons in `/usr/share/pixmaps/` or in the folder with the same name as the application under `/usr/share/...`

Comment: I appreciate the mention of `/usr/share/pixmaps/`, that's more generic if you're copying icons for a specific application.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen Thanks, and yes, the accepted answer is quite limited, especially mentioning non-standard locations while missing standard ones.

Comment: @Vadim Are you shure that you did not create `~/.icons/ ` yourself? I never heard about that folder before.

Comment: @JoKalliauer, check https://askubuntu.com/a/476710/879600, looks like it comes from freedesktop

Answer (score 5):

As a supplementary for the accepted answer: If you don't find the `~/.icons` directory, there may be a `~/.local/share/icons` directory instead (PS: My distro is Ubuntu 16.10).

Comment: I never saw icon stored in `.local/icons` and recognized

Comment: @Anwar It's a typo. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

To add to some of the answers here:

The freedesktop.org standard [requires programs to look for icons in multiple folders in this order](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#directory_layout):

1. `$HOME/.icons` (for backwards compatibility)
2. `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons`, which typically just means `~/.local/share/icons`.
3. `/usr/share/pixmaps`

So if you want a custom icon, your best bet is to find the icon name in `/usr/share/pixmaps`, and then create an image with that same file name in `~/.local/share/icons`.

Comment: Apart from the standard directories (freedesktop.org standard) you can put icons anywhere if you use the full path: Icon=/path/to/myicon.png