# Where do I find the Icons folder (file?)?

Tags: icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are icons stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6009/where-are-icons-stored)

Where do I find the Icons folder (file?)? Then how do I change an apps icon to one of my choosing?