# Where are the Unity Launcher .desktop files?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-2d

I'd like to know which folder the Unity Launcher .desktop files are stored in, as they're not anymore in `/.gconf/desktop` and I need to add a custom application to the launcher bar (adding it in `/usr/share/applications` doesn't seem to be enough).

Where are the Unity Launcher .desktop files?

Comment: Related: [Where are the .desktop icon files stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217331/where-are-the-desktop-icon-files-stored)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

**Globally** in

```
/usr/share/applications
```

**Locally** in

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

If you want to add a custom launcher, create it in `~/.local/share/applications`, make it executable, drag and drop it on the launcher*, and finally pin it (right-click on the launcher item → *Keep In Launcher*).

* Opening it using Nautilus doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Actually, this way the custom icon is not shown but the application icon is instead. Any ideas on how to fix that? I also tried adding the .desktop through gconf-editor but I haven't found the Unity entry.

Comment: You are right, that's probably a bug. Instead you can just drag and drop the .desktop file onto the launcher. To find the favorites list, install the `dconf-tools` package and run `dconf-editor`. The list is stored under *desktop → unity → launcher*.

Comment: You can manually specify the icon to use by adding the following line to the desktop file: `Icon=/absolute/path/to/image.png`

Comment: Just a note that those using snaps may find them in /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/xyz.desktop

Answer (score 14):

Unity 2D looks for .desktop files in the `/usr/share/applications` directory. This can be found by using the following in the Terminal:

```
locate firefox.desktop
```

For me it worked by adding one of the launchers that was already there (eg. *gimp.desktop*) using the following in the Terminal

```
gconf-editor
```

to add an entry to the *favorites* list under `desktop/unity-2d/launcher`.

Comment: I forgot about ```locate``` , thank you! ```/usr/local/share/applications/``` that'where the culprit was!

Answer (score 7):

This question was posted almost 9 years ago, but it still appears on top of searches on this topic. For completeness, since Snaps are now a thing, there are at least 4 locations:

**Globally:**

```
/usr/share/applications
```

`/usr/local/share/applications/` (less common)

**Locally:**

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

**Snaps:**

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications
```

Comment: That's the correct answer today.  At my side a snap was the culprit I wanted to override, and - of course - I grepped EVERYTHING but `/var` for it (everything of snaps are located in `/snap`, right?  Nope, apparently it infects all drives!)

Answer (score 6):

`cd ~/.local/share/applications` is the 1st place that is look in.

Examples from my directory that I used to add quicklists:

```
~/.local/share/applications$ ls
banshee.desktop           gnome-terminal.desktop
chromium-browser.desktop  mimeapps.list
firefox.desktop           nautilus-home.desktop
gedit.desktop             ubuntu-software-center.desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides globally in `/usr/share/applications`, locally in `~/.local/share/applications`, it also has in `/usr/local/share/applications/`. It has similar effects as globally. Some applications choose to put their desktop file in this folder.

Comment: The tip about `/usr/local/share/applications/` was spot on! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I actually found a fix myself! It is necessary to create an entry in alacarte. To customise the icon you must manually edit the icon again from alacarte.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the *right* solution, but more a workaround for a bug in either the launcher or the original .desktop file.