# How to edit .desktop files in unity-2d?

Tags: launcher, icons, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the Unity Launcher .desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40931/where-are-the-unity-launcher-desktop-files)

The changes made for unity .desktop launchers does not take effect in unity 2d. Which folder should i look into to make changes in unity-2d launcher icons?