# Why isn't my custom launcher appearing in the dash?

Tags: launcher

I have a `.desktop` file created by [x2go](http://www.x2go.org/) that I would like to appear in the dash (and be able to drag to the launcher). I put it in `~/.local/share/applications` (as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/40932/19501)) and applied `chmod a+x` (and rebooted), but when I open the dash and search for it (by typing "Tam"), it doesn't appear.

The contents are:

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/Tam.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Exec[$e]=x2goclient --sessionid=20120119165217270
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/other/Desktop.png
Name=Tam X2go Session
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
```

How do I get it to appear in the dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desktop file is invalid. Please replace **Exec[$e]** with **Exec** and try again.

You can use desktop-file-validate to see, if your .desktop file is valid:

```
sudo apt-get install desktop-file-utils
desktop-file-validate ~/.local/share/applications/Tam.desktop
```