# Where are the .desktop icon files stored?

Tags: icons, .desktop, menu, desktop-icons

What system folder on Ubuntu 12.10 are the main menu .desktop icons stored at???

I am having trouble locating....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the Unity Launcher .desktop files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40931/where-are-the-unity-launcher-desktop-files)

Comment: For another great selection of GNOME desktop icons go [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons).

Answer (score 59):

The `.desktop` link files are stored in `/usr/share/applications` for software installed for all users, and `$HOME/.local/share/applications` for things you have installed only for yourself.

The actual icon (image) files are a bit more scattered (since a `.desktop` file can specify their absolute path), but `/usr/share/pixmaps` and `/usr/share/icons` contain a good fraction of them. (icons at  `$prefix/share/icons/` with required fall-back version in hicolor theme can be loaded without the full path, thus such as `Icon=video-display` where `$prefix` can be `/usr`, `/usr/local` or `~/.local`; See specification at [freedesktop.org: Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) )

Comment: Note that many of the icons don't require a full path--you can just use their name and it works. Example: I found this icon I like here: `/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/devices/input-touchpad.png`. So, if I just set the Icon to `Icon=input-touchpad` inside my \*.desktop file, it turns out it works just fine!