# How to find launcher command?

Tags: launcher, command-line

I set a Launcher on the side of my Ubuntu Desktop a long time ago and I included a couple flags (I think that's what they are called) and I would like to run the same program from the terminal using the same flags....but I can't remember what they are.

How can I find what the exact command was for the Launcher I created?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application), see if it helps.

Comment: possibly this too, if you still have the launcher icon http://askubuntu.com/questions/40931/where-are-the-unity-launcher-desktop-files