# How to modify an icon in the Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

When I start Eclipse and add it to the Unity Launcher, I get a ? symbol as shown in the screen shot instead of the Eclipse icon. The same happens for some other applications also and I am not able to differentiate between applications in the Unity Launcher. Also, is there a UI for easily adding launchers and quicklists? Also, how do I change the order of the icons in the Launcher?

[image]

Comment: About the icon: perhaps you'll find what you need somewhere in one of those questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/change-icon-for-an-application-in-unity-launcher or http://askubuntu.com/questions/6009/where-are-icons-stored

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `StartupWMClass=Eclipse` line to the *eclipse.desktop* file.

To detect application's _WM_CLASS_ use: `xprop | grep CLASS`

After the plass appears, just click on your application.

Read [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+question/176213) for further information.