# Setting program logo in Unity launcher - missing icons folder

Tags: 12.04, launcher, icons

My goal is to create a working launcher for PHPStorm which will work in both the desktop and the Unity launcher, using the proper logo, in 12.04.  I followed the instructions here - [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) - to create a launcher on the desktop using the Gnome dialog box.  That worked a treat as far as the desktop was concerned, but dragging the icon to the Unity launcher gave it a weird icon:

[image]

The PHPStorm.desktop file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_GB]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_GB]=PHPStorm
Exec=/home/shane/Software/PhpStorm-4.0.1/bin/phpstorm.sh
Comment[en_GB]=PHStorm
Name=PHPStorm
Comment=PHStorm
Icon=/home/shane/Software/PhpStorm-4.0.1/bin/webide.png
```

Next I tried to follow the accepted answer from here: [How can I change the icon of an application in the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher), but I found that there was no icons folder in ~/.local/share/.  I went ahead and created it, and the rest of the folders mentioned in the answer, ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/ etc.  I then created a phpstorm.png in each folder, at the required sizes.

Next, I edited  my PHPStorm.desktop file to the following and copied it to ~/.local/share/applications/

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_GB]=phpstorm
Name[en_GB]=PHPStorm
Exec=/home/shane/Software/PhpStorm-4.0.1/bin/phpstorm.sh
Comment[en_GB]=PHPStorm
Name=PHPStorm
Comment=PHPStorm
Icon=phpstorm
#Icon=/home/shane/Software/PhpStorm-4.0.1/bin/webide.png
```

After logging back in, my unity launcher icon had disappeared completely, and the icon on my desktop had turned white.

What have I done wrong here?  Why aren't the icons being picked up from the icons folder, and is the initial lack of icons folder something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Regarding the `icons` folder

The only program that has icons in `~/.local/share/icons` is Wine, so no, a default install shouldn't create the folder.

Most installed programs place their icons in `/usr/share/icons`, where all users can access them.

#### Regarding the `.desktop` file

> I went ahead and created it, and the rest of the folders mentioned in the answer, `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/` etc.

The icon has to be placed in a folder called `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/`.

Comment: 22 hours... I can't even vote up with 8 rep!

Comment: Take a look to `desktop-file-validate` command (at least on 16.04+): _Validate desktop entry files according to the Desktop Entry specification 1.1._

Answer (score 8):

I just created this wiki page :) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Sadly I can't even vote up this effort, but thank you!

Comment: Hey, you are welcome :) I don't need your upvote, I like helping out.

Answer (score 7):

I personally prefer adding icons to launcher by first adding applications to unity dash:

1. Install Main Menu via Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Open dash and type "Main Menu".
3. Open menu editor and add your application to proper category (set
   name, icon, command etc).
4. Save and exit.
5. Open dash again type application name and run it.
6. Right-click on icon of your application in launcher and check that
   you want hold it in launcher.

Now you have application in launcher and also in dash :)