# application locked to launcher without icon

Tags: unity, 12.04, launcher, transmission

I tried to drag and drop transmission to my launcher in Ubuntu 12.04, and this is what I got:

[image]

As you can see - there is an icon shaped space where an icon ought to be.  Transmission is locked to the launcher - but I only know this from right-clicking on the space (which gives me the option to unlock it, as well as start the application minimised or with all downloads paused).  Left-clicking on the space does not launch transmission.  Why don't I have a launchable icon of Transmission in my launcher?

Comment: I did install for gnome package and same issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can open a terminal  and use this command:

unity --replace &

to restart unity without reboot or  logout from the session. You can also use the shortcut ALT+F2 with the dash and use the same command.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me with Chrome. I rebooted and the icon appeared. Please tell me if this works for you!