# how to integrate wine with unity icons automatically? [16.04]

Tags: unity, wine, launcher, icons

In my previous ubuntu, using `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`, apps run with wine would automagically be shown with nice icons in unity launcher.

In 16.04, using `ppa:wine/wine-builds`, I installed wine-devel but different apps show all together with the same ugly icon:

[image: Wine icon]

I've tried installing `gnome-exe-thumbnailer` package, which made icons show nicely in nautilus, but not in launcher. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the icon of an application in the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Create `~/.local/share/applications/[application].desktop` with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=
GenericName=
Comment=
Exec=/Path/to/programm
Icon=/Path/to/icon
Categories=
StartupWMClass=
```

For a bit more help on format and details, [this explanation is useful](https://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/) and has helpful links to further information.

Comment: that could be a workaround, but is not what I want. In my previous ubuntu (15.04) the icons were shown correctly for all exes run, without having to manually add launchers for each app. I want to have that back :/

Comment: @melkyades In my Ubuntu 15.10 with unity games installed with games on Linux had the wine icon