# Where is an icon on the Kubuntu desktop stored?

Tags: kubuntu, icons

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04.  I have an icon on my desktop that I would like to reuse somewhere else.  The properties of the icon show the graphic, but not where the actual graphic file is located.  How can I find it?

I note that it would be very nice if each desktop file somehow provided the location of its icon, not just the picture.

Comment: You see the .desktop link files are stored in location _/usr/share/applications_ _/usr/share/icons_

Comment: The icon I'm looking for is not in either of those locations.  But even if it was, I would expect to see the location of the icon by clicking on the icon in the desktop properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Icon file paths**

The KDE is following the Freedesktop icon theme specification https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html . Directory layout: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#directory_layout . From the Askubuntu: [Where are icons stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6009/where-are-icons-stored) .

**KDE4/Plasma4**

Right clicking the desktop icon show an option to look the desktop file.

Either Properties > preview (Folder desktop).

[image]

or Icon Settings > properties (Default desktop).

[image]

If the icon can be found from the default locations then only the icon name will be shown.

[image]

If the icon is not at the default places then the whole path will be shown.

[image]

**Finding things**

Ubuntu find https://help.ubuntu.com/community/find

> locate - list files in databases that match a pattern, i.e. find
>   inside updatedb's list

Ubuntu finding files https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles

Command:

```
locate name.png
```

should show the location of the icon name.png - here it does.