# Where are the thumbnails of a new image located?

Tags: icons, thumbnails

I read [Where are icons stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6009/where-are-icons-stored) about the location of Ubuntu built-in icons (for instance `/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/appsgnome-terminal.png`).

But I am confused about the icon location of a new image, for instance. Let's say I have in a specific directory, a  very large `.eps` or `.bmp` file and I would like to know where its icon(s) is/are located (if somewhere) and how I can access it/them.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the programm that processes the thumbnails, the "icons" are usually located either in `~/.thumbnails/` or `~/.cache/thumbnails/`.

The file name of the thumbnail is the `md5sum` of the full path + `.png` extension. So for finding the thumbnail of a given file you can use this function:

```
find_thumbnail(){
    full_path="file://$(realpath -s "$1")"
    md5name=$(printf %s "${full_path// /%20}" | md5sum)
    find ~/.thumbnails/ ~/.cache/thumbnails/ -name "${md5name%% *}.png"
}


Usage:
======
find_thumbnail /path/to/file.bmp
find_thumbnail ~/Pictures/file.jpg
find_thumbnail file.jpg
find_thumbnail "file with spaces.tif"
```

Comment: +1; This works, but it will not work when there are any spaces in the filename or any directory in it's path. Spaces would have to be converted to `%20` before piping to md5sum.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed this. Is space the only character that doesn't work ?

Comment: It could be possible that other strange characters might lead to confusion, but I think the space is the most common problem. One should not use strange characters in file names anyway even if it is permitted. Some characters (like`$` or a leading hyphen `-`) are well known to confuse Bash. In doubt, one can always rename a file to avoid this.