# Find location for the icon for software updater

Tags: icons, ubuntu-mate

I made a script to start software updater. Now I am trying to find the icon for it.

However, my search found many such icons. Such as in /usr/share/icons/hicolor/ etc.

How can I find the icon that Ubuntu uses for software updater?

Is there a method that will work for any program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went to the directory `/usr/share/applications/` with Nautilus. There I searched for a filename containing "update", and found the file `update-manager.desktop`.

This file contains this line within:

```
Icon=system-software-update
```

I expect that if you stick this line into your custom desktop launcher, it will result in the same icon shown as in the original.

---

Nevertheless, one can search `/usr/share/icons/` for filenames containing this string, which returns a bunch of updater icons.

Mind you, not all of these results are real graphics files in there, some of them are just symlinks referencing a smaller number of real graphics files; but you can find your way among them by inspecting their file properties through the right-click context-menu.

Bonus: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1004271/1157519) suggests further locations in the filesystem (both in the `/` and `/home/` partitions) that may contain icons.

---

I guess at this point one could narrow down one's search for just the icon set that the system is currently using.

On a stock Ubuntu 20.04, the standard settings app's "Appearance" tab does not show the name of (or allow altering) the icon set.

The `gnome-tweaks` app however, on its "Appearance" tab shows the name of (and allows changing) the icon set used on the desktop.

Knowing the name of the used icon set allows for narrowing the search down to its corresponding directory.

Comment: Thanks, I found it here. /usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/apps/system-software-update.png @Levente