# Where is the Lubuntu default backlight icon stored?

Tags: lubuntu, icons, backlight, icon-themes

I have recently installed Lubuntu and have everything working as I want, except for the backlight icon in the taskbar I have at the top of my screen.  I can't work out where it is being sourced from.

I have looked through the folders mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6009/where-are-icons-stored), and any searches for backlight (or lite) don't turn up anything that looks like the icon I have.

The icons for wifi/battery/etc are coming from the WhiteSur-dark theme, from the symbolic folder.  There is no backlight icon in there (i created one but that doesn't seem to work) so I presumed it was pulling it from the default theme (which is breezy), but the breezy icon folder contains no backlight icon at all either.

See a screenshot of the relevant area below.

[image]

Does anyone know where that backlight icon (the one next to the power button) is coming from?  Or how I need to name the backlight file in the WhiteSur-dark theme folder so that it is recognised?

Comment: You haven't provided any release details, but have you looked in `usr/share/lxqt/lxqt-panel/` (esp. the setting in `backlight.desktop` file, or `icon=` line)

Comment: @guiverc I am using 20.10.  Thank you, the backlight.desktop uses the icon I am looking for so I am getting closer!  The icon=brightnesssettings.  But I still can't find the icon itself. I've looked in pixelmaps and the theme folders

Comment: I haven't confirmed this, but a `find -name brightnesssettings*` (within /usr/share/) finds files of matching names in ./icons/Papirus/, a `dpkg -S` of one of those files shows `papirus-icon-theme` package as source... and https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/lubuntu-desktop shows that as installed by Lubuntu...    I've not written this up as an answer (nor provided all output) as I didn't confirm anything..  (sorry for delay)